# C# HttpWebRequest or cURL wanting continuous connection

Tags: c#, curl, httpwebrequest, webclient

I am trying to find out a continuous connection between url and my code. I am sending data to http in json every 500m/s. However the connection is being disconnected and connected again when I checked WireShark. I tried three(httpwebrequest, cURL, webclient) and what I want is them to give continuous connection. Now, I just want cURL to do that. Here are the codes that I have tried and a capture from wireshark to let you understand better.

cURL
100m/s function

```
 static private void SystemStatusTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
        {
            cpuusage = CPU,
            availablememory = AVAILMEMORY,
            availableharddiskspace = AVAILABLEHD
        });
        Easy.WriteFunction wf = SystemStatusWF;    //response
        SystemStatusEasy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_URL, SYSTEMSTATUS_SERVER);
        SystemStatusEasy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json);
        var resultOK = SystemStatusEasy.Perform();
        SystemStatusEasy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, wf);  //response            
    }
```

Main Function

```
 static void Main()
    {            
        Curl.GlobalInit((int)CURLinitFlag.CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

        SystemStatusEasy = new Easy();
        var slistHeaders = new Slist();
        slistHeaders.Append("Content-Type: application/json");
        SystemStatusEasy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        SystemStatusEasy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slistHeaders);
        SystemStatusEasy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        SystemStatusEasy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_POST, true);
        SystemStatusEasy.SetOpt((CURLoption)213, 1L); //keep alive(not sure in c#)
        SystemStatusEasy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, false);
        SystemStatusEasy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
        SystemStatusEasy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");

        systemStatusTimer = new Timer(500);
        systemStatusTimer.Elapsed += SystemStatusTimer_Elapsed;
        systemStatusTimer.Start();            

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

[Wireshark Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwLN5.png)

As you can see on the Wireshark Capture, they are being disconnected by fin /ack and then connects again by Syn. I just want one SYN when the program starts and then FIN/ACK at the end of progress. Any help would be apprecieated.

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep alive the connection? You can't ensure it, the best you can do is what you already did, ask the server to keep alive the connection, but if the server decides to close the connection after sending a response there's nothing you can do to mantain it open.

Comment: So is it Keep alive which opens the connection between the server and  the program until the server closes the connection? If it is may I know how to make keep alive connection in cURL? I did this(SystemStatusEasy.SetOpt((CURLoption)213, 1L);) because I couldn't find the right api for .NET but I know in C, it does have   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1L);. It could be found in https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE.html . I know that CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE is in enum and have number of 213. So I did try to put it like SystemStatusEasy.SetOpt((CURLoption)213, 1L);

Comment: But not sure I did right or not..There is not much information about c# and cURL..T^T Any suggestion for poor struggling guy?

Comment: No idea, never used cUrl from c# (and I don't think it's a good idea, if the system does not have cUrl installed it will not work) Why not use a good old plain HttpWebRequest?

Comment: Thanks by the way. I already tried HttpWebRequest but it creates new URL connection when the code gets here. var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(SYSTEMSTATUS_SERVER);. If you want to help and look for codes that i have tried with httpWebrequest,  I can post it down..

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I did with HttpWebRequest.

```
static HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest;
static void Main()
    {
        httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(SYSTEMSTATUS_SERVER); //

        systemStatusTimer = new Timer(500);
        systemStatusTimer.Elapsed += SystemStatusTimer_Elapsed;
        systemStatusTimer.Start();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

static private void SystemStatusTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
        httpWebRequest.ServicePoint.SetTcpKeepAlive(true, 100000, 1000);
        Console.WriteLine(cookieContainer);

        Console.WriteLine("system Status 100m/s : {0}\t{1}\t{2}", CPU, AVAILABLEHD, AVAILMEMORY);
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
            {
                cpuusage = CPU,                    
                availablememory = AVAILMEMORY,
                availableharddiskspace = AVAILABLEHD
            });

            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            var result_header = httpResponse.Headers;

            Console.WriteLine("The response of sysStatus from server : " + result);              
        }
    }
```

Finally the result from wireshark.
[wireshark capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib1Zl.png)

Oh well, it only gives one SYN and one FIN/ACK. However I am continuously sending system data to server 500m/s. Why did it gave me FIN/ACK and not sending data afterwards?